# Correct setings for pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Having difficulty getting Mezzanine to connect to Postgresql via Docker

In my postgresql.conf I have:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In my pg_hba.conf I have:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             samenet                 trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have PORT in settings.py set to '' but I have PORT defined in postgresql.conf to 5432.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the database you are trying to connect on the same machine? Have you restarted PostgreSQL after changing the config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that port mapping is properly configured https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/
If your app is running in one container and postgresql server is running in another container, you need to link containers together.
By the way you are trying to establish connection via localhost and you have md5 authentication method there. For debug purposes change authentication method to trust. You should EDIT this line in your pg_hba.conf NOT to ADD another line.

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

The best way to debug connection issues is to use psql utility.